# Facebook Pagination Limit with Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, api, pagination, limit

this is my first post here.

I'm trying to query all places within my city limits (Winnipeg) using geo-location data and a radius of 15,000 meters.

This is working somewhat well with the query:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
                $session,
                'GET',
                '/search?type=place&limit=100&center=49.89542,-97.13853&distance=15000'
            );
```

The pagination afterwards works once or twice but ends up cutting me off after a variable 180-220 results. I noticed the pages returned are all from downtown (center query string) and start to spread outward, but it stops after only 2 city blocks.

Here is the loop I have in use for iterating through additional results:

```
$paging = $graphObject->asArray()['paging'];

            $i = 0;
            while(property_exists($paging, "next") && $i <= $times)
            {
                $next_url = $paging->next;
                $json = file_get_contents($next_url);
                $obj = json_decode($json);

                foreach($obj->data as $page)
                {
                    $page_ids[] = $page->id;
                }
                $paging = $obj->paging;

                $i++;
            }
```

I have researched issues with API limits but nothing that comes even close to only 200-ish results.

Is there possibly something I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you try to change the distance parameter? If the result number is not changed with distance, then there's probably a limitation in the result.

Comment: I did, yes.

The troubling thing is that the limit changes slightly each time I get a response, but not by the amount it should based on the distance (between 190 - 230 over an extra 20km)